# ¿Me hace falta un método?

Tags: java

El ejercicio consiste en hacer un applet que contenga una opción de selección Choice. Esta debe contener 3 colores azul verde y rojo. al momento de ser seleccionado uno de estos el fondo debe colocarse de ese color.

Yo llevo este código pero no se que me hace falta.

```
package Semana2;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class AppleInterfaz extends Applet implements ItemListener {    
    Choice colores;

    public AppleInterfaz(){
        colores = new Choice();
        colores.add("Verde");
        colores.add("Azul");
        colores.add("Rojo");
        add(colores);
    }

    public void star(){

    }


    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        repaint();

    }

    public boolean action(Event ev,Object obj){ 
        if(ev.target.equals(colores.getSelectedItem().equals("Verde")))
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        if(ev.target.equals(colores.getSelectedItem().equals("Azul")))
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        if(ev.target.equals(colores.getSelectedItem().equals("Rojo")))
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: El método star() debería ser start(). Usa @Override para garantizar que realmente estás escribiendo bien el método.

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo por qué estás utilizando un applet para realizar esto, pero aquí te dejo una solución que funciona correctamente:

```
package Semana2;    
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class AppleInterfaz extends Applet implements ItemListener {    
Choice colores;

public AppleInterfaz(){
    colores = new Choice();
    colores.add("Verde");
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    colores.add("Azul");
    colores.add("Rojo");
    add(colores);
    colores.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            cambiacolor(arg0);

        }
    });
}

public void cambiacolor(ItemEvent ev)
{
    if(((String)ev.getItem()).equals("Verde"))
    {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if (((String)ev.getItem()).equals("Azul")) {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

}

}
```

Solo decirte que, si quieres que algo cambie cuando se realice una determinada acción (evento) sobre un componente, debes implementar un "listener" sobre dicho componente, de forma que si se produce la acción ésta sea detectada.